# circleci permission denied error when using machine executor

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I would like to use the machine executor so that I can run some component tests with docker-compose. My workflow fails on the checkout step and throws this error: `Making checkout directory "/opt/my-app" Error: mkdir /opt/my-app: permission denied`

Here is the yaml for the component_test stage in my workflow:

```
component_test:
  machine: true
  working_directory: /opt/my-app
  steps:
    - checkout
```

If I use docker instead of the machine executor then I don't get any permission issues:

```
component_test:
  machine: true
  working_directory: /opt/my-app
  steps:
    - checkout
```

But, I'd like to be able to use docker-compose and thus need to be able to run the machine executor. Has anyone seen a permission issue like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change the working directory into something in `/home/circleci` or just exclude it complete as it's optional.

Right now, the `circleci` user runs the `checkout` step, which doesn't have permission to git clone to the working directory you choose.

Also, I wouldn't use `machine: true` as that is deprecated. Specify an image: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#available-machine-images

Comment: I would not say that the machine type is deprecated given that circle doesn't say that. Machine type is necessary if you need to spin up multiple docker containers that communicate with each other and your container, manipulate the network stack, etc.

Comment: The type/key isn't deprecated. Using `machine: true` instead of `machine` and then specifying an image is deprecated. I work at CircleCI and I am the one who deprecated it. I agree with your assessment of why to use the machine executor. That I'm denying. Just specify an image instead of using the value of `true`.